# How can I schedule different Selenium tasks to run in certain intervals

Tags: selenium, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, schedule

I'm trying to get a Selenium job to run based on certain parameters such as  one job runs every 2 weeks, one on the end of the first and 3 week of every month, one on the 15th and last day of every month etc.

Is there a way to do this? Use python to schedule? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you need to use a crontab on your server, have you tried it?